# how to return json array by API call

Tags: node.js, api

Sir, I have already constructed the request to create a json array set.

```
request('https://testing.com/fund.jsp', function (error, response, body) {
...

 console.log('jsonArray : ', jsonArray);


});
```

If I want to make the API get by localhost:3000/getFund andreturn the jsonArray as result, would you please tell what should I do next
 ?

Comment: Can you show us your route handler for getFund?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [ExpressJs](http://expressjs.com/). If so, you can use `response.json`

```
response.json({ jsonArray : jsonArray });
```

For more, you can have a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_response_object.htm)

Comment: I don't think this will work, purely because `response` in this instance is the 'response' from his `request` call. You're on the right track, but you're also guessing he's using express  which isn't tagged in the question. I'm assuming it may be 'res' but based on the code that has been provided so far I believe this answer would fail

Comment: @TommyBs I assume he is using ExpressJs. And here is the reference
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_response_object.htm

Comment: Even then your answer still won't work as `response` has been overwritten as one of the callback variables to the `request` call

Comment: Answer edited. I have to use and register  the routes.